# Is there any way possible where a variable length of arguments can be accepted by a netlogo function?

Tags: netlogo

I have some code that is repeated multiple times and I am trying to make a function so that I just call that function with args, but I wonder if a variable number of args is accepted by the same function in netlogo?

For example:

```
to set-attributes [ x-occupiedepitopes x-size x-exempt_from_immobilisation x-aggregated ]
  set heading random 360
  set occupiedepitopes x-occupiedepitopes
  set size x-size
  set leader self
  set exempt_from_immobilisation x-exempt_from_immobilisation
  set aggregated x-aggregated
end

to set-attributes2 [ x-occupiedepitopes x-size x-exempt_from_immobilisation x-aggregated x-color ]
  set heading random 360
  set occupiedepitopes x-occupiedepitopes
  set size x-size
  set leader self
  set exempt_from_immobilisation x-exempt_from_immobilisation
  set aggregated x-aggregated
  set color x-color
end
```

The above two functions are identical apart from one extra arg `#x-color`

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

NetLogo doesn't support variable argument numbers (at least not in user procedures), nor does it support [overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

You could still make your code less repetitive by doing something like:

```
to set-attributes [ x-occupiedepitopes x-size x-exempt_from_immobilisation x-aggregated ]
  set heading random 360
  set occupiedepitopes x-occupiedepitopes
  set size x-size
  set leader self
  set exempt_from_immobilisation x-exempt_from_immobilisation
  set aggregated x-aggregated
end

to set-attributes2 [ x-occupiedepitopes x-size x-exempt_from_immobilisation x-aggregated x-color ]
  set-attributes x-occupiedepitopes x-size x-exempt_from_immobilisation x-aggregated
  set color x-color
end
```

Another approach would be to accept a list as an argument and then have your procedure behave differently depending on the number of items in the list, but that might be more complicated than it's worth.

Comment: Thank you for answering that. I considered lists but I was afraid it would slow down the simulations as the functions is called by each turtle.

Comment: NetLogo lists are implemented using [Scala vectors](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html), which have effectively constant random access time, so accessing list elements is very fast. The bottleneck for you would be constructing the argument list. I think it's an interesting exercise, but I'm still doubtful it's worth the added complications in your model.

Comment: It might be worth taking a step back and try to think about how you could restructure your problem to avoid needing that kind of functions in the first place. In many years of NetLogo programming, I never encountered the need for this, so maybe it's just a matter of program structure. Otherwise, maybe you should consider using another ABM platform with support for that kind of thing...

Comment: I have around 10-15 breeds and each breed undergoes association, dissociation reactions. So I use this function to define the attributes each time a new breed hatches or is re-set to another breed. Within a big ask of all turtles, I sub-ask each breed to undergo all association and dissociation reactions and then call this function. I don't know if that is a good way to structure this, I am a beginner programmer and basically a biologist. Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: Not sure how much that will help, but maybe you could consider having "template" agents with the default values that you are more likely to need, and then use those to `hatch` new agents that will inherit these values from their parent.